# React-Native AWS advice for global state management

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, state-management

I have an mobile app with a stack:

- REACT-NATIVE (UI)
- AWS COGNITO (AUTHENTICATION)
- AWS AMPLIFY
- AWS APPSYNC (GRAPHQL QUERIES / MUTATIONS)

...initially I wasn't using any global state management library but I will soon need a way to handle global state better across all the screens. The app has users that store a lot of content (photos, videos etc on it).

In the past I have used Redux and Mobx for apps. Neither of which I am a massive fan of.

**My question is: in 2022 with this tech stack, does anyone have suggestions of state management libraries they have used / like / think would play nicely with what I have already set up?**

Comment: Could you say more about what you will keep in state, and what you didn't like about the solutions you tried?

Comment: I will keep things like:
-> a profile picture (in profile screen + tab bar + message screen)
-> name (on multiple screens)
-> photos / text that is part of an art work thats has been uploaded that will appear on multiple screens

Comment: ...What I don't like about redux:
-> so much boiler plate code and not suer if its over kill if I am using AWS Appsync (graphql) / Amplify

...Mobx I just found quite confusing, didn't pull the state through properly when I was trying on previous projects but that was possibly because I didn't set it up properly...

Comment: I guess I am asking if anyone has a similar stack / can advise with what I have already set up...

Comment: Redux is way better now with the addition of Redux Toolkit, but it sounds like overkill for what you're doing.  I find Mobx confusing also.  Recoil, Zustand, or even simple React Context might work for you, idk if you have explored those.  My impression is that RN handles image caching pretty well (see [link](https://rangle.io/blog/image-caching-in-react-native/)) and it isn't common to store binary data in state.